# Node following cameraNode with its physicsBody

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm developing an AR game and I need to add a node to the scene which will follow `cameraNode`.
I have tried to attach that node to the cameranode's hierarchy like that:

```
self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(node)
```

And the node really follows the camera but its physics body doesn't move with it as I see running app in debug mode.

```
self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin, SCNDebugOptions.showPhysicsShapes]
```

How should I add node to perform both conditions?:

1. The node is following camera moves
2. Its physicsBody is following camera moves too

Answer (score 0):

For node that is following a camera you need to use a `SCNDistanceConstraint` and `SCNLookAtConstraint`.

Read about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/constraints).

Also use `SCNPhysicsVehicle` class to simulate realistic physics of motion behaviour.

Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsvehicle).

Comment: I tried using both SCNDistanceConstraint and SCNLookAtConstraint and i haven't get what i want. At first the node is in wrong orientation although its orientation was set earlier. Secondly the node is not following camera moves.
So i don't think this solution is suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

Everything became much easier. If you want to add a node following the camera with its physicalBody you should add it to the cameranode hierarchy like i did before but (its important) you should make its body kinematic type.

```
let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: node))
```

Now it works perfectly